# How can i open the page with a active tab depending on the previous route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following page with three tabs("Info", "Rules", and "Wiki"):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Navbar } from '../components';

function Information() {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState('instrucciones');

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar>Información y normativa</Navbar>
      <div className="relative pt-16 pb-16 min-h-screen w-screen bg-gray-200">
        <div className="w-full overflow-visible ">
          <div className="flex overflow-x-scroll no-scrollbar max-w-full mt-4 ml-4 whitespace-nowrap">
            <button
              onClick={() => setSelectedTab('instrucciones')}
              className={`flex-1 py-2 px-4 text-center text-black bg-white rounded-full ${
                selectedTab === 'instrucciones'
                  ? 'bg-primary font-bold active'
                  : 'hover:border-stone-400'
              } mr-4`}
            >
              Instrucciones
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => setSelectedTab('normativa')}
              className={`flex-1 py-2 px-4 text-center text-black bg-white rounded-full ${
                selectedTab === 'normativa'
                  ? 'bg-primary font-bold active'
                  : 'hover:border-stone-400'
              } mr-4`}
            >
              Normativa
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => setSelectedTab('wiki')}
              className={`flex-1 py-2 px-4 text-center text-black bg-white rounded-full ${
                selectedTab === 'wiki'
                  ? 'bg-primary font-bold active'
                  : 'hover:border-stone-400'
              }`}
            >
              Wiki
            </button>
          </div>
          {selectedTab === 'instrucciones' && (
            <div>
              <h1 className="mt-6 ml-3 p-3 text-left text-lg font-bold text-black">
                INSTRUCTIONS
              </h1>
              
            </div>
          )}
          {selectedTab === 'normativa' && (
            <div>
              <h1 className="mt-6 ml-3 p-3 text-left text-lg font-bold text-black">
                NORMATIVA
              </h1>
              
            </div>
          )}
          {selectedTab === 'wiki' && (
            <div>
              <h1 className="mt-6 ml-3 p-3 text-left text-lg font-bold text-black">
                WIKI
              </h1>
              
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Information;
```

I´m trying to open it with the tab wiki active when the user clicks on the Information button from the page /wiki (that´s the route), for any other page, it should open with the tab Info. How can I go about it? I´ve tried using useLocation but i received a empty ''.

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include all relevant code that is related to `react-router`, e.g. any router, routes, and links, as part of a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so we've better context what the code is doing and what any issues may be?

Answer (score 0):

you recieved empty because you are not using any routing at all, you are using conditional rendering instead, which is wrong. you have to change a lot of things(you have to use things like BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link) so I recommend reading docs about routing https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router